# How can i edit my code to change the decimal seperator from dot to comma. (text is included in the output)

Tags: php, csv

I know that this question might have been answered before but i haven't been able to find a solution for my code yet. My problem is that my file has decimals seperated with dot and i need to change that into comma.

**Here is my code**

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-upload'])){
    copy("$sourcepath/$latest_filename","$copy/$latest_filename");
    // Here i split the csv file, from second line. and using the first and fourth lines as the headers.
    if (($openfile = fopen("$copy/$latest_filename", "r")) !== false) {

        $header1 = fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";"); // consume, but don't use

        $csv->createPalleTable($latest_filename);
        $csv->insertPalleTable($latest_filename, array_map("utf8_encode", fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";")));

        $delimiting_row = fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";"); // consume, but don't use 

        $header2 = fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";"); // consume, but don't use

        $csv->createCsvTable($latest_filename);
        while ($getdata = fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";")) {
            $csv->insertCsvTable($latest_filename, array_map("utf8_encode", $getdata));
        }
    }
}
```

**From what i have read myself to is that i need to use number_format. but i have no idea how i should use it in my code.**

I know that my code can be abit confusing when you dont know what the method does. and i can explain if needed. but they pretty much does what they say they do.

Any help is appreciated.

**Sample output**

1   1) Height 130       avg(L)Y     inspection_dimension_scalar 130.00  129.00  -1.00   1.00    0.00

2   1) hk Height 130        avg(L)Y     inspection_dimension_scalar 130.00  130.00  -1.00   1.00    0.00

3   2) Ø131,5       Ø       inspection_dimension_scalar 131.00  131.00  0.00    0.00    0.00

4   3) dk2 Ø199,3       Ø       inspection_dimension_scalar 199.00  198.00  -1.00   1.00    0.00

**The problem is the 1.00 should be 1,29 as an example**

Hope it helps seeing what the method does.

**The code inside `$csv`**

```
 //functionen til at vise den sidste nye tabel fra databasen.
public function getCsv($latest_filename)
{
    return $this->db->toList("SELECT * FROM `$latest_filename`");
}

public function getPalle($latest_filename)
{
    return $this->db->toList("SELECT * FROM `Palle_$latest_filename`");
}
public function createCsvTable($latest_filename)
{
    return $this->db->toList("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$latest_filename`(
        id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        -- FK_product INT(11),
        -- FOREIGN KEY (FK_product) REFERENCES product_tb(product_id),
        Name VARCHAR(50), 
        Datum VARCHAR(50), 
        Property VARCHAR(50), 
        Criterion VARCHAR(50), 
        Type VARCHAR(50), 
        Nominal DECIMAL(10,2), 
        Actual DECIMAL(10,2), 
        Tolminus DECIMAL(10,2), 
        Tolplus DECIMAL(10,2), 
        Dev DECIMAL(10,2))
      ");
}

public function insertCsvTable($latest_filename ,$fncsvdata)
{
    return $this->db->toList("INSERT INTO `$latest_filename` (`Name`, `Datum`, `Property`, `Criterion`, `Type`, `Nominal`, `Actual`,`Tolminus`,`Tolplus`,`Dev`)
    VALUES (:Name, :Datum, :Property, :Criterion, :Type, :Nominal, :Actual, :Tolminus, :Tolplus, :Dev)",
        [
        ':Name' => $fncsvdata[0],
        ':Datum'=> $fncsvdata[1],
        ':Property'=> $fncsvdata[2],
        ':Criterion'=> $fncsvdata[3],
        ':Type'=> $fncsvdata[4],
        ':Nominal'=> $fncsvdata[5],
        ':Actual'=> $fncsvdata[6],
        ':Tolminus'=> $fncsvdata[7],
        ':Tolplus'=> $fncsvdata[8],
        ':Dev'=> $fncsvdata[9]
        ]
    );
}

public function createPalleTable($latest_filename)
{
    return $this->db->toList("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Palle_$latest_filename`(
        id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        -- FK_product INT(11),
        -- FOREIGN KEY (FK_product) REFERENCES product_tb(product_id),
        Palle_nr VARCHAR(50), 
        Varenummer VARCHAR(50), 
        Ordre_nummer VARCHAR(50), 
        Operatoer VARCHAR(50), 
        Maskine_nr VARCHAR(50), 
        Raavare_batch_nr VARCHAR(50), 
        Dato_ur_stillet VARCHAR(50), 
        Klokke_fuldsvejst VARCHAR(50), 
        Fuldstoebning_af_klokke VARCHAR(50),
        Afgratning_af_overflade VARCHAR(50), 
        Vaegt DECIMAL(10,2))
      ");
}
public function insertPalleTable($latest_filename ,$palledata)
{
    return $this->db->toList("INSERT INTO `Palle_$latest_filename` (`Palle_nr`, `Varenummer`, `Ordre_nummer`, `Operatoer`, `Maskine_nr`,
     `Raavare_batch_nr`, `Dato_ur_stillet`,`Klokke_fuldsvejst`,`Fuldstoebning_af_klokke`,`Afgratning_af_overflade`,`Vaegt`)
    VALUES (:Palle_nr, :Varenummer, :Ordre_nummer, :Operatoer, :Maskine_nr, :Raavare_batch_nr, :Dato_ur_stillet,
     :Klokke_fuldsvejst, :Fuldstoebning_af_klokke, :Afgratning_af_overflade, :Vaegt)",
        [

        ':Palle_nr' => $palledata[0],
        ':Varenummer'=> $palledata[1],
        ':Ordre_nummer'=> $palledata[2],
        ':Operatoer'=> $palledata[3],
        ':Maskine_nr'=> $palledata[4],
        ':Raavare_batch_nr'=> $palledata[5],
        ':Dato_ur_stillet'=> $palledata[6],
        ':Klokke_fuldsvejst'=> $palledata[7],
        ':Fuldstoebning_af_klokke'=> $palledata[8],
        ':Afgratning_af_overflade'=> $palledata[9],
        ':Vaegt'=> $palledata[10]
        ]
    );
}
```

Comment: Here check that [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: i have checked it, but i haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: Show the sample output you are getting now

Comment: I'm guessing you want to convert that value before using `$csv->insertCsvTable($latest_filename, array_map("utf8_encode", $getdata));` ? If that is the case, how can you access it within `$getdata` variable? Are you using `$getdata[0]` or `$getdata->myItem` or something else ?

Comment: hmm think you might be right. that i should convert the data before the `array_map("utf8_encode", $getdata)`. but dont exacly know how to do so